# Creating SqlConnection object takes ages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#, and when I call to the `SqlConnection` constructor it takes ages until it goes to the next instruction. I tried creating the object with the connection string and without it and setting timeout but it still taking the same time.

Here is some of the code...

```
string dbConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlServer2012_2"].ToString();
string query = "SELECT * FROM testTable";
List<carTestModel> model;
//MessageBox.Show(dbConn);

try {
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(); //HERE IS WHERE IT TAKES AGES
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = dbConn;

    using(sqlConn) {
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        model = new List<carTestModel>();

        while(rdr.Read()) {
            var testRow = new carTestModel();
            testRow.id = (int)rdr["carIdTest"];
            testRow.name = (string)rdr["carNameTest"];

            model.Add(testRow);
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
catch(SqlException exc) {
    MessageBox.Show("Fail! " + exc.Message);
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well, show us what the connection string looks like!!

Comment: Could it be that there's a problem with name resolution?

Comment: Are you sure it's `new SqlConnection()` that's taking the time and not `sqlConn.Open`, also what is the contents of `dbConn`? Does `ToString()` produce the expected result for a `ConnectionStringSettings` object?

Comment: @Robert Tried using IP and server name...

@RGraham I'm quite sure, because I went instruction by instruction and there is where it takes like 5min, 10 or more... and the result of ...ToString it like... `"Server=192.168.200.106; Database=carDB; User Id=car; password=123456;timeout=5;"`

Comment: What happens when you try to connect with SQL Management Studio or similar?

Comment: @Robert Server its installed on a VirtualMachine in other PC and when I conect using SSMS it connects immediately

Comment: It seems that you are accessing a remote server. SO, how you are connected to this DB server- over Internet, Intranet or extranet?

Comment: @AnupamSharma What makes you think `192.168.200.106` is a remote server? `192.168` is certainly a common internal IP range. This question has no answer. There is no way `new`ing an object should take that long. What I would do is remove **all** of that code and do `var conn = new SqlConnection()` - if that still causes an issue your IDE has a problem

Comment: @RGraham I made a new project and just added `var conn = new SqlConnection();` and it keep taking a loooot of time... so there is no solution... should I try VS 2013?

Comment: Definitely. Or try resetting your user profile settings or something - something is clearly blocking execution there